# Hide <TD> when there is nothing in gridview in ASP.NET using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, data-binding, gridview

I am trying to hide a TD named ImportnatInfo in a table when the gridview is empty. This gridview has one column from a table in a database to show. When this gridview is empty I want to hide the TD.

The following is the asp code:

```
<td runat ="server" ID="ImportnatInfo" 
                style="width: inherit; border: 5px double #585858; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;
                height: inherit; background: #FFFFFF; background-position: center; border-radius: 25px;" 
                enableviewstate="True" visible="False">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None"
                    DataSourceID="ImportantSqlDataSource">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Importatnat_Info" SortExpression="Importatnat_Info">
                            <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="10px" />
                            <FooterStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="10px" />
                            <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="10px" />
                            <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="10px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ImportantSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AgainConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Importatnat_Info] FROM [StationInfoTable] WHERE ([StationNo] = @StationNo)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStationNames" Name="StationNo" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                            Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />
            </td>
```

And the VB.net code is the following:

```
If GridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        ImportnatInfo.Visible = False
    Else
        ImportnatInfo.Visible = True
    End If
```

I have dropdownlist and i choose something everytime so if there is nothing in the grid to view, i want the whole TD to be invisible. the TD that im trying to hide when it is empty, the thing the TD is always visible because when there is nothing in the gridView Vb add   so it won't be empty. so i thought i should use the datasource and still not sure what to do. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: It's not becoming visible, is the issue?

Comment: I have dropdownlist and i choose something everytime so if there is nothing in the grid to view, i want the whole TD to be invisible.

Comment: Yes, but what is actually happening?

Comment: the TD that im trying to hide when it is empty, it is not and it is always visible because when there is nothing in there Vb add &nbsp; so it wont be empty. so i thought i should the datasource and still not working. Any idea who to do that?

Comment: Setting the cell to visible false should do the trick (I would think).  Just to see if the issue is with the TD, you could put an asp:Panel in the TD and show/hide that, see if the results are the same.  Also, you debugged and saw GridView1.Rows.Count is absolutely zero?

Comment: Which cell do you want me to set to false. Also, yes i have debugged it few time and the GridView1.Rows.Count is Zero at first and then it is one all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        GridView1.DataBind()
    ImportnatInfo.Visible = True
    If GridView1.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count >= 1 Then
            If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text.Trim() = "&nbsp;" Then
                ImportnatInfo.Visible = False
            Else
                ImportnatInfo.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ImportnatInfo.Visible = False
    End If
```

Yours is working good but you just need to add Else to show the TD after you check it is not

Answer (score 2):

Check the type of row (via `row.RowType`); it's probably not a data row, but an empty row or header row or something else. So you need to make sure rows with an ItemType of Item or AlternateItem are the type you are counting.  You can see more detailed information about this property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx).

**EDIT:** You can use LINQ to filter the results of the appropriate type:

```
Dim cnt = GridView1.Rows.Where( _
  Function(i) i.RowType = DataControlRowType.Item OrElse _
              i.RowType = DataControlRowType.AlternateItem).Count()
If cnt = 0 Then
    ImportnatInfo.Visible = False
Else
    ImportnatInfo.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Where do i have to put Row.ItemType and do I need to write anything before Row.ItemType? for example GridView1.Row.ItemType? if yes i tried this and i cant, and Do you want me to do some thing else?

Comment: I got the name wrong, it's row type (included MSDN link above).  For debugging purposes, to verify if what I said is right, when the rows is set to 1, in the debugger do: GridView1.Rows(0).RowType, and post back what the result is.

Comment: I checked it and you are right but how can i used it? I have tried few things but still didnot work.

Comment: Cool I put ur code in Page_load and I get error for the "Where" and it says it is not a member of 'System.WebUI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'

Comment: in the error section I got, Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type.

Comment: I don't know what that's about.

Comment: Or you can try it and see why?

Answer (score 2):

Try hooking into the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected.aspx) event of your data source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ImportantSqlDataSource" OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AgainConnectionString %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [Importatnat_Info] FROM [StationInfoTable] WHERE ([StationNo] = @StationNo)">
  <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStationNames" Name="StationNo" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
  </SelectParameters>
```

Note **`OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected"`**

Then in your code behind

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected
    ImportnatInfo.Visible = e.AffectedRows > 0

End Sub
```

Your gridview may have rows even if no data is returned: headers, footers and/or a now data found message.

**UPDATE**

Also try the following

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selected
    ImportnatInfo.Visible = e.AffectedRows > 0
    Gridview1.Visible = e.AffectedRows > 0

End Sub
```

This should also set the gridview to not show when there are no rows, regardless of the visibility of the `td`. I would also try moving your datasource outside of the `td` it shouldn't make a difference, but it may.

If after trying this if the gridview is hidden, but the td remains visible there may be something happening later in the page life cycle that is affecting the visibility of the td.

Comment: the TD (ImportantInfo) is still visible all the time?

Comment: I have tried many many things and it seems no way i can do it. so, hopefully you will be online back again soon. :)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `SqlDataSource1_Selected` event in you code behind and manually check the value of `e.AffectedRows` let us know what value you get when there is no data returned.

Comment: Thanks I figuard the answer out and i will post. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
  GridView1.DataBind()
    ImportantInfo.Visible = True
    If GridView1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text.Trim() = "&nbsp;" Then
                ImportantInfo.Visible = False

            End If

        End If
    Else
        ImportantInfo.Visible = False
    End If
```

ASP.NET always leave a space   when there is nothing in the GridView. So, I check if it is empty or not if not i check if it is the space or the GridView has some data.

Comment: I'd still argue you're better off interrogating the data instead of the bound grid view. In fact you'd be best off interrogating the data **before** binding the gridview

Comment: And how i can do that. At least i try it?

Comment: and why it is better of to interrogating the data before binding the gridview?

Comment: Have a quick look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860, particularly the section on Accessing Data. Use the dataset object which gives you access to tables and rows returned. You can then check the number of tables and rows returned if there are no rows there is no point binding the datagrid and you can set your td to not visible. My answer is an alternate way of checking the rows returned. Also note you do not need to manually bind the grid when using a SQLDataSource control. This may also be causing issues.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I will check the link you gave now. :)